# String concatenation adds tab character instead of space in VS 2012

Tags: c#, sql, string, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a C# code which generates sql query to be executed using the code as below:

```
strQuery = "select * from ";
strQuery += tableName + " where";
stryQuery += " columnName = " + columnValue; //where columnValue is a parameter (@XYZ)
```

This code works fine in VS 2005. But, after upgrading the solution to VS 2012, third line causes problem. Normally the query should look like

```
select * from tableName where columnName = columnValue
```

But in VS 2012, query looks like

```
select * from tableName where\tcolumnName = columnValue
```

I have no idea why it is happening at all, and if so, why only with the leading space in the string concatemation.

Edit: More details:

In the code, there is a function called CreateSQLQueryString, a snippet of which is above. This function creates a base query with @XYZ as the column values. Then the same is passed to another function called CreateParameterArray which creates an array of parameters for all such @XYZ values. Both the base string and the parameter array is then used to execute the query.

Now, I checked the string received by CreateParameterArray function, and that one receives the string with tab characters. So, no other function is causing a problem. It is just this string concatenation that causes trouble.

Edit:

```
void GetRows(connectionID)
{
string strQuery;
strQuery = "select ";
if (condition1)
strQuery += " PartName,";
if (condition2)
strQuery += " PartPrice,";
...
if (condition10)
strQuery += " PartQuantity";

strQuery += " where "

if (whereclause1)
strQuery += " partName= '" + partname + "'"; //partname = "@PartName"
if (whereclause2)
strQuery += " partPrice= '" + partPrice + "'";
...

Var ParamArray[] = CreateParameterArray(strQuery);

/// code to create connection object based on current server info

//execute query
var resultSet = connectionObject.ExecuteQuery ( strQuery, ParamArray[], connectionID);
//display result
UpdateDisplay(resultSet);

}

CreateParameterArray(string query)
{
 //code to add a value in parameter array for every reference of "@" in query.
}
```

This is the basic idea of the code. I have replaced the columnnames with generic ones.

Final Edit:

Turns out, there was another isPostBack condition added during upgrade. No idea how, or why. But after removing it, everything works. There was a trim function called on the query string, during initialization of the page, which was moved to the isPostBack condition. Now that trim function is called properly, query works fine. Still no idea, why space is replaced by a tab character, but thankfully trim replaces those characters with 4 spaces. System works fine now, but I am still baffled by how it happened.

Comment: Please post a short but complete program demonstrating this problem. I'm *highly* suspicious - it goes against everything I've ever seen for any C# compiler. My guess is that there's something going on either in your code or in your diagnostics. Additionally, you refer to VS2012 in two places, and VS2014 in another - was the latter a typo?

Comment: Also, use parameterized SQL :)

Comment: What Jon said! plus I think you'll find a tab in the source code - a typo not an upgrade error...

Comment: @Jon Yes, that was a typo. I meant 2012 only. And actual program is some 1000 lines of code. The function that creates the base sql query has some 50 lines similar to this. Basically, that function creates a sql querystring, that is then updated by another function (createParameterArray) to replace the columnValue parameter with the actual value. I checked the other function, and that function is receiving the query string with tab characters.

Comment: @jitendragarg: I didn't ask you to post the existing full code. I asked you to post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. In other words, you should create a copy of your code, and cut more and more out of it until you've *just* got a tiny program (ideally a small console app) which demonstrates the issue... or more likely, by then you'll have found the issue in your code.

Comment: I got it. Let me try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `String.Format`?

`String.Format("select * from {0} where columnName = {1}",tableName, columnValue);`

Comment: I am using it in a later stage. This part just creates the base query, which can range from 1 liner to 50 liner. So, based on user input, it just adds more conditions to base query. Once the query is created, I use a parameter array and string format to replace all "@ParameterName" with the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your whitespace to make sure that the upgrade didn't convert the space to a tab?

You can use Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W to see the whitespace.

Comment: I checked. It is space, atleast according to the IDE.

Comment: Actually, I found the tab characters. Turns out, it was not the upgrade, as the original project also had the same tab characters for whitespaces. Weird thing is in VS2005, the query does not contain tab character at all. So, now I have a new problem.